# Deploying application to EKS through gitLab CI pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gitlab, amazon-eks

I am going through some blogs to understand exactly how we can setup a gitlab CI pipeline that deploys our containerized app on aws `EKS`( Though I haven't started actual implementation yet). I would most of ten see below command as part of `yaml` script:

```
kubectl -f apply deployment.yaml
```

I understand what this command does. It basically refreshes the deployment on cluster which makes the cluster to pull the image again( If we have specified it in yaml file).

The question here is how does gitlab runner knows which cluster it is going to deploy to, or in other words, how do we provide the location of our `EKS` cluster to the runner and give the runner privilege to deploy to this cluster?

The blogs either lack sufficient information about this thing or the information seems ambiguous to me. Please help me to understand how this flow would be implemented.

Thanks.